# How to call Oracle function which return Oracle record type in MyBatis

Tags: java, oracle, spring, mybatis

I have record type in package specification:

```
 TYPE Payment_Capabilities IS RECORD(
    pp_partial_payment NUMBER(1) DEFAULT 0,
    co_advance_payment NUMBER(1) DEFAULT 0,
    dp_deposit_payment NUMBER(1) DEFAULT 0,
    dr_deposit_repay   NUMBER(1) DEFAULT 0,
    wp_wallet_payment  NUMBER(1) DEFAULT 0,
    wr_wallet_repay    NUMBER(1) DEFAULT 0,
    ss_prepaid_payment NUMBER(1) DEFAULT 0);
```

and function which returns this type. I'm using MyBatis integration with Spring. How to call (using MyBatis XML Mapper) this function and map result to POJO object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<select id="identifyPaymentCapabilities" parameterType="PaymentCapabilities" statementType="CALLABLE">
    DECLARE
        v_payment_capabilities APS.Payment_Capabilities;
    BEGIN
        v_payment_capabilities := APS.get_payment_capabilities(#{customerId, javaType=Integer, jdbcType=NUMERIC, mode=IN});

        #{partialPaymentPP, javaType=Integer, jdbcType=NUMERIC, mode=OUT} := v_payment_capabilities.pp_partial_payment;
        #{advancePaymentCO, javaType=Integer, jdbcType=NUMERIC, mode=OUT} := v_payment_capabilities.co_advance_payment;
        #{depositPaymentDP, javaType=Integer, jdbcType=NUMERIC, mode=OUT} := v_payment_capabilities.dp_deposit_payment;
        #{depositRepayDR,   javaType=Integer, jdbcType=NUMERIC, mode=OUT} := v_payment_capabilities.dr_deposit_repay;
        #{walletPaymentWP,  javaType=Integer, jdbcType=NUMERIC, mode=OUT} := v_payment_capabilities.wp_wallet_payment;
        #{walletRepayWR,    javaType=Integer, jdbcType=NUMERIC, mode=OUT} := v_payment_capabilities.wr_wallet_repay;
        #{prepaidPaymentSS, javaType=Integer, jdbcType=NUMERIC, mode=OUT} := v_payment_capabilities.ss_prepaid_payment;
    END;
</select>
```